# send prevented default submit button by ajax form submission

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form , that I'm sending its  by ajax to php file to manipulate database.

//html

```
<form id='editUserForm' action='insert.php' method='post'>
  <input type='text' name="userName/>
  <input type='text' name="userLastName/>
  <input type='submit' name='editUser' value='submit'/>
</form>
```

//ajax

```
    (function($){
    function processForm( e ){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'insert.php',
            dataType: 'text',
            type: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
                alert("Done");
            error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                console.log( errorThrown );
            }
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    }

    $('#editUserForm').submit( processForm );
})(jQuery);
```

//insert.php

```
  if(isset($_POST['editUser'])){
if(isset($_POST['chUserStatus'])){
    $active='َactive'; 
}else{$active='disabled';}
$query="update admins set user='$_POST[chUserName]', pass='$_POST[chUserPass]',email='$_POST[chUserEmail]',level='$_POST[chUserLevel]',status='$active' where id=$_POST[userId]";
$result=mysqli_query($dbCnn,$query);
echo(mysqli_error($dbCnn));
```

}
The problem is here, because my function is preventing form default submit, it doesn't post submit btn name/value to insert.php. How can I send it as parameter to insert.php?

Answer (score 1):

`serialize()` does not retrieve any attributes from `button` elements, you would need to add that information yourself, if you need it:

```
var $button = $('#editUser :submit');

// in the $.ajax...  
data: $(this).serialize() + '&' + $button.prop('name') + '=' + $button.val(),
```

Comment: why is'nt it possible: data:{$(this).serialize(), 'submit':'ok'},

Comment: That wouldn't work because you'd have the querystring encoded within a single parameter, added to another querystring. eg: `foo.com?foo1%3Dbar1%26foo2%3Dbar2&submit=ok`

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#search").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
            url: 'insert.php',
            dataType: 'text',
            type: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
                alert("Done");
            },
            error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                console.log( errorThrown );
            }
        });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="search">
<input name="q"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
```

see the result in console.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in the form data object before serialize, ore even append it after serialize.
Personally I'll just add a new hidden input like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="editUser" />
```